# Dual-Mode Terminal or TTY?

Tags: command-line, tty

You know how you can jump into a full-screen terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but is there a way to have a possible DUAL terminal mode?

Something that would provide you with 2 terminals (or more) in a cli interface? Something that you either boot into instead of the GUI, or just jump out of the GUI (like the F7 thing).

Comment: I think what you are looking for "terminal multiplexers" like `tmux` or `byobu`?

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: is there any way that you can edit that to say F1 instead of F7? I got that wrong obviously lol. F7 allows you to exit back into the GUI. Sorry. I would, but I dont know how you edited it to look like that the first time lol

Comment: F2*. Sorry, I got it wrong again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, you're switching to a different `tty` or [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console).

These virtual consoles work much like a Terminal, such as `gnome-terminal` or `xterm`, except they aren't loaded by your Windows Manager, and you will likely need to login to them.  Be warned, if you login and fail to log out, that `tty` will stay active and someone else can just switch over and use it.

That means that just like you can use other tools, such as `screen` or `tmux` to multiplex your terminal, you can do so in your `tty`.  One of the benefits from using one of these multiplexers is that they support multiple 'tabs', have ways to have multiple shells or terminals in a single `tty` or terminal window (your goals) as well as support resuming of the session later.  There a lot of guides on how to use both `screen` and `tmux`, but I would recommend you taking a look at [The Tao of tmux](https://leanpub.com/the-tao-of-tmux/read), as that is very detailed and doesn't assume you know a lot about everything else.  There are images there that will help explain how you can split your `tty` into multiple terminals, and how to switch between them.

If you wish to automate something for when you login, you will want to look into how sourcing files at login, such as `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and other [shell initialization files](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html) work, while also looking into how others have solved similar problems.

Without more specifics, I hope that this helps explain that you can use a multiplexer that supports splitting to accomplish your goal.

Comment: This was exactly the answer that I've been searching for! Thank you, so much. I'm starting the book you recommended now! Cheers!

Comment: No worries.  If you're not using a GUI, these `tty`s are great, but if you're using Windows Manager/X11, I'd recommend looking into using a multiplexer in a terminal emulator in your GUI and using that in full screen and on a different workspace vs playing with `tty`s but that's for you to decide.  Best of luck.

Comment: thank you! I was really just looking for a way to have the choice to jump into something more light weight and easier to use, but i still wanted to be able to have the convenience of switching back to the GUI for things like managing networks and stuff... but want to 95% of the time be inside of the terminal

Comment: If you like tiling your terminal, you may like a tiling windows manager to tile your tiled terminals :D [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/)

Comment: I've heard about that, I think I'll go check it out! Oh man... I just figured out that you can press ctrl+alt+f1-f2-f3-f4-f5 for DIFFERENT tty's. I feel so dumb now